# Eliminar caracter en un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe donde una columna tiene un moldes de la siguiente manera:

> JK-4185-4
>   HE-3294-A-7
>   ZY-160-3
>   UA-4026-5
>   XC-485233-3
>   XC-4
>   XC-48-3-2

y lo que deseo es quitar el versionado de dichos moldes, es decir quitar lo que esta después del segundo guión, si no tiene versión que quede igual, quedando de la siguiente manera:

> JK-4185
>   HE-3294
>   ZY-160
>   UA-4026
>   XC-485233
>   XC-4
>   XC-48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de proceder, pero creo que usar regex con `pandas.Series.str.extract` es una muy simple de resolver tu problema. Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
Moldes
JK-4185-4
HE-3294-A-7
ZY-160-3
UA-4026-5
XC-485233-3
XC-4
XC-48-3-2
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)
df["Moldes"] = df["Moldes"].str.extract(r'^([\w]+-?[\w]+)')
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       Moldes
> 0    JK-4185
> 1    HE-3294
> 2     ZY-160
> 3    UA-4026
> 4  XC-485233
> 5       XC-4
> 6      XC-48
> ```

La expresión usada en este caso es:

- `^`  fija la posición al comienzo de una línea.
- `()` primer grupo de captura.

  - `\ w` coincide con cualquier carácter de palabra.

    - `+` cuantificador, coincide tantas veces como sea posible (codicioso)
  - `-` coincide con el carácter `-`.

    - `?` cuantificador entre cero y una vez.

Como comentaba, existen más formas, como usar `str.split` junto a `str.join`:

```
df["Moldes"] = df["Moldes"].str.split("-", n=2).apply(lambda l: "-".join(l[:2]))
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto amigo, estaba intentándolo con expresiones regulares pero no encontraba la lógica, aunque  `str.split y str.join`, también funciona perfecto, verificare algunos casos particulares, por el momento ha tomado todos los casos posibles. muchas gracias